# Install PostGIS from source for specific PostgreSQL version

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have two versions of PostgreSQL on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04) one is 9.1 and the other one is 9.4.

I want to install from source (I have my reasons) postgis 2.1.2 over PostgreSQL 9.4, but when I ran configure it finds only 9.1.

How to specify 9.4 version during compilation process?

Comment: it's usually a flag to ./configure

Comment: `configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config` is one way.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at this [page](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html) it suggests that you can set it as a flag on the `./configure` command line

```
--with-pgconfig=FILE
PostgreSQL provides a utility called pg_config to enable extensions like PostGIS to locate the PostgreSQL installation directory. Use this parameter (--with-pgconfig=/path/to/pg_config) to manually specify a particular PostgreSQL installation that PostGIS will build against.
```

On my machine it seems to be in `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin` but I only have one version of PG installed.

If you can't find the specific one then you can (re)create it by running

```
./configure; make
```

in a new download of the source. It will then be in `src/bin`.

Comment: I read that, but the problem is that I have only one pg_config and it is for 9.1.

Comment: have a look in the src or local bin directory of your 9.4 build (I assume you built them from source too)

Comment: I'm not sure because I didn't install it on fist place. I made full surch on the machine for pg_config, the only one for 9.1 shows up.

Comment: I'd start again on a clean VM if it was me, I don't know what the various installers do but it probably isn't what you want

Comment: I just had the same problem because of a legacy server that i inherited. I didn't have the pg_config either so I downloaded source postgres source, built it in a working directory and used the newly generated pg_config to re-build postgis. I then copied the postgis-2.4.so to /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib restarted the postgres service and it was working